# Java OOM: no heapdump created

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory, weblogic, jrockit

I'm getting OOM of memory issue on a long running application (3~5 hours) with the following symptoms

1. -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError produce an empty dump
   http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6784422
2. Exception in thread "[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '21' for queue:
   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
   getNewTla

Is there any other JVM options I can add to find out the exact cause I have the above symptoms. The application owner is refuse to allow me like increase xmx xns xms or anything with exception of collecting more data.

jrockit-jdk1.6.0

Comment: You can try going to the Administration Console and do a thread dump `Server -> <server_name> -> Monitoring -> Threads -> Dump Thread Stacks`. Also check http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=4464 for more ideas

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using jrockit, you need to bump up the tla

```
 -XXtlaSize:min=10k,preferred=256k
```

Comment: I'm considering doing that but I need evidence to back me up before I am try that command